# How to disable drag thumb on a ScrollBar in WPF?

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, drag

Two question:

1. How to disable drag thumb on a ScrollBar in WPF?
2. Is there a way to limit drag thumb position? like LargeChange or SmallChange?

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit the template of the ScrollBar control and set the IsEnabled property of the Thumb to false
2. Not sure you can do that directly from code or XAML but you might add 2 new DP to a control which inherits the ScrollBar class and then change the template to have this new feature

Comment: how to edit ScrollBar's template? and change its IsEnable property?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be usefull for someone
If you wanna disable drag thumb there two way:

1. Rewrite controll for your scrollbar
2. In controll template do not rewrite thumb, just use rectangle or just leave it empty

Example:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                            <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Row="1" />
                                <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}" Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z"/>
                                <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="ThumbReplacer" Fill="{DynamicResource ScrollColor}"/>
                                <RepeatButton Grid.Row="2" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}" Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```